# Solving for compatibility equations, expanding a derivative problem

Tags: algebra-precalculus, multivariable-calculus, trigonometry

Introduced compatibility equations in school, for MOC, slight confusion in deriving the
equations.

**Given:**$$\frac{d(V\sin\theta)}{d(V\cos\theta)}=\frac{M^2\sin\theta\cos\theta\mp \sqrt{M^2-1}}{1-M^2\sin^2\theta}$$

**Compatibility Equation:**$$\theta=\mp\sqrt{M^2-1}\frac{dV}{V}$$

How do you expand the LHS equation into below from the given, don't quite understand where the $\cos(\theta)$ in the numerator and the $\sin(\theta)$ come from:

$$\mathbf{\frac{\sin\theta dV+V\cos\theta d\theta}{\cos\theta dV-V\sin\theta d\theta}}=\frac{M^2\sin\theta\cos\theta\mp \sqrt{M^2-1}}{1-M^2\sin^2\theta}$$

Comment: Write $\dfrac{d(V \sin \theta)}{d (V \cos \theta)}=\dfrac{\dfrac{d(V \sin \theta)}{dV}}{\dfrac{d (V \cos \theta)}{dV}}$

Comment: @MariusS.L. so essentially its just the derivative of $V\sin\theta$ with respect $V$ ,similar process for the denominator then?

Comment: Sorry, I made a mistake. It is the total derivative here. We actually have $d(V \sin \theta)=\dfrac{\partial (V\sin \theta)}{\partial V}\cdot dV +\dfrac{\partial (V\sin \theta)}{\partial \theta}\cdot d \theta.$ This is the total derivative as differential form expressed in its two coordinates.

Comment: Ok, that checks out with the equation, thanks